# Prestashop sidebar columns

Tags: php, css, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have installed a theme in prestashop 1.6 and I'm trying to enable the left sidebar in products list page AND to product page only.

But when I go to "Advanced settings" of the theme, I can't find those two pages, as you can see in the image below.

[image]

Is there another way to enable the sidebar in some pages, hard coded or from the database? Or any other solution?

Comment: First link is full of spam when viewed on mobile

Comment: Sometimes it's bugged, you need to set 1 in the database table. Worked for me

Comment: Set 1 to which table, columns? Can you please give me some more details?

Comment: you need to set the columns in `theme_meta` table, the name of the page is in `meta` table - look at the `id_meta` field column to match it.